# I can not build and then run an ionic app using Xcode on my iphone 7, the Build failed

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

After pressing 'build and run' button I get such errors...

```
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/slavik/Desktop/loooks_ionic_new/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/OptimizationProfiles/CordovaLib.profdata'

the description is:

 CompileC /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.o /Users/slavik/Desktop/loooks_ionic_new/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target: CordovaLib)
        cd /Users/slavik/Desktop/loooks_ionic_new/platforms/ios/CordovaLib
        export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
        /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=c99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -fprofile-instr-use=/Users/slavik/Desktop/loooks_ionic_new/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/OptimizationProfiles/CordovaLib.profdata -fembed-bitcode-marker -index-store-path /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Cordova-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include -I/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -DDEBUG -include /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/17494842693492805826/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.dia -c /Users/slavik/Desktop/loooks_ionic_new/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.m -o /Users/slavik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/loooks_ionic-fawfdrklmzcwsffvzcvicqellmun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/arm64/NSDictionary+CordovaPreferences.o
```

[I made a screenshot that probably may help to understand the configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpSDw.png)

How to solve this error and finally run the app successfully?

Comment: Hi , Actually  I’m having trouble understanding your question,Can you please reproduce your question  and please mention your conflicting clearly

Comment: Hi, okay I reproduced the question, thanks

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10 by chance?

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@sunilk/you-are-encountering-this-issue-as-apache-cordova-in-their-latest-release-added-telemetry-to-d03732719dc1

```
ionic cordova build ios --no-telemetry
```

Comment: mm, have you tried to remove the whole ios folder and regenerate the ios project?